# Why does size of a Docker image reduce after flattening the image?

Tags: docker

I have flatten a Docker image following the instruction given here:

https://tuhrig.de/flatten-a-docker-container-or-image/

I have seen the size of the image is reduce by ~21% after flattening. Now, it seems like efficient in terms of deployment time(because of the size) but I am worried the flattening process removes some of the contents of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Flattening removes files that are in one layer and later removed or overwritten in another layer. Even doing a permission change will result in a copy-on-write (files being copied to the other layer) with the new permission. A flattened image does remove the ability to utilize the cached layers for faster `docker build` commands and may result in a lot more data being transmitted over the wire if your destination host already has the base layers for your image.

Instead of flattening your images, my own advice is to follow the [Dockerfile best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/) to minimize how big your layers are in the first place.